# How does one know when and where to use integrals while deriving an equation?

Tags: education, integration, calculus

The thing I want to know is the use of integrals in mathematics. I'll be glad if someone explains it in any of the derivation.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. Typically these things are very situation-dependent.

Comment: In very general terms, though, you can often turn a sum into an integral when taking the continuum limit.

Answer (score 2):

In physics we often use integral science when dealing with rates of change(e.g. in a derivation of kinematic) or even in cases of calculating potential energies as work done is force multiplied by distance moved in direction of force, the area of a force vs. distance graph can give the energy. Moreover there are **numerous** other examples involving sums and rates of changes etc. Here are a few:

Now for the first example;

1. Deriving $s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$:
   For uniformly accelerated motion the equation of velocity is, $v=u+at$ which is;
   $$\frac{ds}{dt}=u+at$$
   So we integrate on both sides to get:
   $$s=\int({u+at})dt$$
   $$s={ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2}$$
2. For deriving the equation electric potential *at a point* due to a point charge $Q$, which is the work done per unit charge to bring a positive charge from infinity to that *point*; Now the Force on a **unit positive charge** is given by:
   $$F=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}$$
   So the work done to bring the charge from infinity is a *sum/integral* of all the products of F and small changes in r (*dr*) so electric potential, $\phi$ is given by:
   $$\phi=\int_R^{\infty}({F})dr$$
   $$\phi=\int_R^{\infty}{\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}}dr$$
   Taking limits from R(distance to point) to infinity.
   $$\phi=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0
   R}$$
   Which is the formula to be found.

Answer (score 0):

Not to sound condescending, but the answer is "whenever you need to integrate."  Integrals are tools that are useful for a purpose, and you use them when you need them.  Addition, multiplication, logarithms, exponentiation, and any other mathematical operations are the same: tools that are useful for a purpose that get used when they're needed.

Because of this, I don't think you're going to get a very specific answer.